# How to Set a MaxDate for DateTimePicker in .NET MVC?

Tags: javascript, jquery, razor, datetimepicker

I've been trying to set a MaxDate value for my DateTimePicker but I couldn't find any useful way to do so. I have tried

```
$("#datepicker").datepicker({maxDate: '0'});
```

And

```
$(function () {
    $('#datetimepicker6').datetimepicker();
    $('#datetimepicker7').datetimepicker({
        useCurrent: false //Important! See issue #1075
    });
    $("#datetimepicker6").on("dp.change", function (e) {
        $('#datetimepicker7').data("DateTimePicker").minDate(e.date);
    });
    $("#datetimepicker7").on("dp.change", function (e) {
        $('#datetimepicker6').data("DateTimePicker").maxDate(e.date);
    });
});
```

But none solved my problem. In my razor file I have these two datetimepickers:

```
<div class="form-group" style="width: 15%;">
<label for="example-search-input" class="col-form-label">Start:</label>
@Html.TextBoxFor(u => u.reportFrom, new { @class = "form-control", type = "date", @id = "datetimepicker6" })
```

```
<div class="form-group" style="width: 15%;">
    <label for="example-search-input" class="col-form-label">End:</label>
    @Html.TextBoxFor(u => u.reportTo, new { @class = "form-control", type = "date", @id = "datetimepicker7" })
</div>
```

And I have this script right under this page;

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $("#tarihsecici").datepicker({ maxDate: '0' });
    });
</script>
```

Can someone help please, it is critically important for my project and I have tried to solve it many times but none worked.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Here you can try this code for datepicker.

```
$("#datetimepicker6").datepicker({
      format: 'dd-mm-yyyy',
      autoclose: true,
  }).on('changeDate', function (selected) {
    var startDate = new Date(selected.date.valueOf());
      $('#datetimepicker7').datepicker('setStartDate', startDate);
  }).on('clearDate', function (selected) {
      $('#datetimepicker7').datepicker('setStartDate', null);
  }); 

  $("#datetimepicker7").datepicker({
      format: 'dd-mm-yyyy',
      autoclose: true,
  }).on('changeDate', function (selected) {
      var endDate = new Date(selected.date.valueOf());
      $('#datetimepicker6').datepicker('setEndDate', endDate);
  }).on('clearDate', function (selected) {
      $('#datetimepicker6').datepicker('setEndDate', null);
  });
```

Comment: Unfortunately it also didn't work. I wonder if it is about the template I'm using. It seems to have its' own, better looking DateTimePicker but still I think I should be able to access a datetimepicker using jQuery and datetimepicker's ID...